# updating states in a object of local state in react js

Tags: reactjs

I want to update min & max in the state. If I update only min & max, other two states are becoming empty.

```js
constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  this.state = {
    param: {
      one: [],
      two: [],
      min: 100000,
      max: 5100000
    }
  };
}
```

This is my code.

```
select_price(price) {
     this.setState({ param: {min:price[0], max:price[1]}});
}
```

Comment: Where is your code that updates your state? Are you using `setState()` or `replaceState()`?

Comment: I'm using setState()

Comment: can you post your `setState()` command?

Comment: Please share code for state update

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you are replacing whole state with new state. you should do something like this

```
  select_price(price) {
     let paramState = {...this.state.param}; //works with es6 only
     paramState.min = price[0];
     paramState.max = price[1];
     this.setState({ param: paramState });
  }
```

As suggested in edit by @markm247, Another way of doing this

```
  select_price(price) {
     let paramState = {...this.state.param, min:price[0],max: price[1]};
     this.setState({ param: paramState);
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

A quick fix is to get the whole document, change the specific items and set the state:

```
doc = this.state.param
doc.min = price[0]
doc.max = price[1]}
this.setState({ param: doc });
```

Not sure if you can apply a `$set` kind of operation with `setState`

Comment: It's in local state. local state can not be accessed by props.
this.props.param.get() is throwing error : 
Cannot read property 'get' of undefined

Comment: replace with `this.state.param.get()` then?

Comment: `this.state.param` without `.get()`?